# How to print star pattern which accepts odd number as an argument?

Tags: javascript

I am new at this printing star pattern 
I want to print the following star pattern using JavaScript:
If n=5

```
* * * * *
  * * *
    *
```

In my code I am taking the input "n" from the user and I have also put a condition to check wheather the user input is an odd number. If it is an odd number then only for loop will be exceuted. I also successfully added the spacing but revered the star pattern but still I am not able to print the above pattern

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
 let n = parseInt(prompt('Enter the odd number '));
        if(n > 99){
            alert("please enter number between 3 to 99 ")            
        }else if(n%2!=0){
            for(var i=n;i>=1;i--){
            for(var k=1;k<=(n-i);k++){
                document.write("&nbsp;")
            }
            for(var j=1; j<=i;j++){
                document.write("* ")
            }
            document.write("<br/>")
        }
    }else{
        document.write("enter odd number")
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't understand the logic of the required star pattern.
Help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reach to your expected pattern, loop step must be 2. Then first loop modified like this:

`for(var i=n;i>=1;i=i-2){`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<script>
 let n = parseInt(prompt('Enter the odd number '));
        if(n > 99){
            alert("please enter number between 3 to 99 ")            
        }else if(n%2!=0){
            for(var i=n;i>=1;i=i-2){
            for(var k=1;k<=(n-i);k++){
                document.write("&nbsp;")
            }
            for(var j=1; j<=i;j++){
                document.write("* ")
            }
            document.write("<br/>")
        }
    }else{
        document.write("enter odd number")
    }
</script>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```